ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException
I keep getting an exception when trying to unzip to a folder with elevated permissions. I am trying to avoid having to externally change the permissions since it would have to be on a large number of computers.
System.Exception: Error transferring files
---> System.Exception: Error unzipping C:\TransferFiles\ZipFolder.zip to C:\ProgramData\Tecan
---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path C:\ProgramData\Tecan\SVNRoot\SystemSW_1.0\format is denied.
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable1 unixCreateMode)
at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable1 unixCreateMode)
at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileStreamOptions options)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToFile(ZipArchiveEntry source, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractRelativeToDirectory(ZipArchiveEntry source, String destinationDirectoryName, Boolean overwrite)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(ZipArchive source, String destinationDirectoryName, Boolean overwriteFiles)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String sourceArchiveFileName, String destinationDirectoryName, Encoding entryNameEncoding, Boolean overwriteFiles)

I thought maybe it was because the file did not have an extension, but unzipping to other folders with lower permission level does allow you to unzip a file like that.
I am using Visual Studio Code to develop and run my program. I have tried running as an administrator, which solved the issue for some other permission related issues I was having but was not able to get around this. I also attempted to change the access rule and change the owner:
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(destination);
DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

FileSystemAccessRule fileSystemAccessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule
(
    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null),
    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
    AccessControlType.Allow
);

directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(fileSystemAccessRule);
directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);

DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(destination);
DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

var owner = directorySecurity.GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount));
var newOwner = new NTAccount(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

directorySecurity.SetOwner(newOwner);
directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);


ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory - you probamly mean ZipFile.ExtactToDirectory?

I am only having issue with the ExtractToDirectory

Then can you please correct the title?

I cannot do that

Found the issue. The file I was trying to overwrite was readonly and it had nothing to do with permissions since I was running as admin. I created a ZipArchive and changed the File attribute to Normal to overwrite it and then reverted back to the original attribute.


using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFilePath))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        using (Stream es = entry.Open())
                        {
                            string entryDestination = Path.Combine(destination, entry.FullName);
                            if (entryDestination.EndsWith("/"))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(entryDestination);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var originalAttribute = File.GetAttributes(entryDestination);
                                File.SetAttributes(entryDestination, FileAttributes.Normal);
                                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(entryDestination, FileMode.CreateNew))
                                {
                                    es.CopyTo(fs);
                                }
                                File.SetAttributes(entryDestination, originalAttribute);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }




Read here
Add an app.manifest, the client will have to run your app(and run as admin). You should have access to the folder with elevated permissions.
I use a similar approach to installing ffmpeg within system32 folder

nice! so I already am running the program as admin. I ran Visual Studio Code as admin and also ran the exe as admin and still had this issue. I think might have something to do with the ZipFile static class itself
